# How to use a package in Angular2 without publishing it to npm

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a package which is published to npm and we are successfully using the package in our angular2 applications by defining the dependency in package.json as

```
"dependencies": {
   "somesharedmodule": "^1.0.21",
 }
```

and in our components as `import {SharedService} from 'somesharedmodule'`.

Now we dont want to make the library public(not interested to make private library too).My question is - i have a module in some folder of my local system.Can i use this module in my application without making the package published in npm. can somebody please guide me the alternatives to use a module in my application without publishing it?

Comment: I think you are looking for [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)

Comment: With npm link the module is created as shortcut in my actual application so that i can use it during development but when i try to build it is failing

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what exactly you want to do... Bu there are lots of options:

- npm link https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link
- use github private repo:

  `"dependencies": {
      "ng2-resource": "https://github.com/{nickName}/{repoName}.git"
  }`
- link your IDE to use local folder as `node_modules`
- manually copy/paste library into project's `node_modules`

Comment: Can you explain more what you said about `link your IDE to use local folder as node_modules` and `manually copy/paste library into project's node_modules`